# Woocommerce not putting javascript in footer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

Ok so I have a custom wordpress theme and I have installed woocommerce. But the javascripts that are normally added to the footer are not being brought in:

- the only plugins i've got running are woocommerce and advanced custom
  fields
- my theme has add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' ); is in my
  functions.
- i have a woocommerce.php in my theme folder
- I have the    copied directory in 'woocommerce' in my theme to
  override the plugin files but have not edited them.
- wp_footer(); is in the footer

Im tearing my hair out as to why its not bring it in.

Comment: When you switch to default WP theme the js are correctly added?

Comment: Nope. It was doing it site wide, regardless of theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea how or why but it has resolved itself.

Comment: Maybe some server cache issue? Do you have an apc cache on your server for instance?

Comment: I think it could have been that. My config.rb (for SASS) got uploaded which might have caused some weirdness?